# How to get xpath to an element with xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, xpath

While working on a specific element in the XML tree, I need to get the xpath of this element. For example /A/B[4]/C/D[1]/Age
If using lxml, it is very simple: Simply use tree.getelementpath(child)

But for a reason I need to use xml.etree. How can it be done there?

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: This is what I have in lxml, and I need the xml.tree equivalent: 
tree = etree.parse(filename)

root = tree.getroot().tag

print(root)

for node in tree.iter():
    for child in node.getchildren():
        if child.text:
          if child.text.strip():
              print(tree.getelementpath(child) + "=" + child.text.strip())

Comment: Can you post the xml (or at least some relevant parts)?